Django: how to pass javascript code from python to form field attributes?
I'm using django-bootstrap-daterangepicker plugin that allows to create the following Django form:
from django import forms
from bootstrap_daterangepicker import fields

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):                                                                                                                                              
    date_range = fields.DateRangeField()

Everything works as expected until I want to add some dynamic daterangepicker-specific options like predefined ranges, that should be evaluated on every page refresh:
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    },
})

If I use:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django import forms
from bootstrap_daterangepicker import fields, widgets

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    date_range = fields.DateRangeField(
        widget = widgets.DateRangeWidget(
            picker_options = {
                'ranges': { 
                    'Last week': [
                        (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).isoformat(),
                        datetime.now().isoformat(),
                    ],
                },
            },
        ),
    )

then dates are evaluated on server start and not re-evaluated at page refresh.
Is there a way to tell Django to treat string as javascript code to pass it to rendered page as code, not as string? Or are there other ways to solve this problem?
